# TypeORM Request to auto generated table nestjs

Tags: mysql, mariadb, nestjs, typeorm

I have 2 tables: `teams` and `users` which have two middle tables which are autogenerated by TypeORM.

Here is how the table looks like in MySQLWorkbench:

[image: screenshot MySQLWorkbench]

And here are snippets for the entities.

#### users.entity

```
import { Teams } from './teams.entity';
import { Feedbacklog } from './feedbacklog.entity';
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany, ManyToMany, ManyToOne } from 'typeorm';

@Entity({
    name: 'users',
})
export class Users {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
        name: 'userID',
    })
    userID: number;

    @Column('varchar', {
        nullable: false,

        length: 100,
        name: 'email',
    })
    email: string;

    @Column('varchar', {
        nullable: false,

        length: 200,
        name: 'password',
    })
    password: string;

    @Column('varchar', {
        nullable: false,
        length: 20,
        unique: true,

        name: 'username',
    })
    username: string;

    @Column('varchar', {
        nullable: false,
        length: 35,

        name: 'firstName',
    })
    firstName: string;

    @Column('varchar', {
        nullable: true,
        length: 35,

        name: 'lastName',
    })
    lastName: string | null;

    @Column('int', {
        nullable: false,
        default: 0,

        name: 'receivedFeedbacks',
    })
    receivedFeedbacks: number;

    @Column('int', {
        nullable: false,
        default: 0,

        name: 'givenFeedbacks',
    })
    givenFeedbacks: number;

    @Column('varchar', {
        nullable: false,
        length: 20,
        default: 'User',

        name: 'role',
    })
    role: string;

    @ManyToMany(type => Teams, team => team.user)
    team: Teams[];
    @OneToMany(type => Feedbacklog, feedbacklog => feedbacklog.receiver, { eager: true })
    received: Feedbacklog[];

    @OneToMany(type => Feedbacklog, feedbacklog => feedbacklog.sender, { eager: true })
    sent: Feedbacklog[];
}
```

#### teams.entity

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany, ManyToMany, JoinTable } from 'typeorm';
import { Users } from './users.entity';
@Entity({
    name: 'teams'
    ,
})
export class Teams {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
        name: 'teamID',
    })
    teamID: number;

    @Column('varchar', {
        nullable: false,
        length: 40,

        name: 'projectName',
    })
    projectName: string;

    @Column('date', {
        nullable: false,

        name: 'startDate',
    })
    startDate: string;

    @Column('date', {
        nullable: false,

        name: 'endDate',
    })
    endDate: string;

    @Column('int', {
        nullable: false,

        name: 'teamMembers',
    })
    teamMembers: number;

    @ManyToMany(type => Users, {
        eager: true,
    })
    @JoinTable()
    user: Users[];

    @ManyToMany(type => Users)
    @JoinTable()
    teamLead: Users[];
}
```

I'm using NestJS and the database is MariaDB.

How can I access those middle tables?

Comment: I moved the code inside the question, as links can break.